# Changing the message when using UpdateProgress

Tags: ajax

I dont know if this is possible or not but I was wondering if there is a way to change a message in the UpdateProgress when using Ajax. I tried put the message in a label and for some reason i cant do it that way so just wondering you can how to do that. Here is what I have below.

```
   <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
          Logining In...
    </ProgressTemplate>
   </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this

Page:

`<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div id="overlay">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_wait" runat="server" clientIDMode="Static">Logining In...</asp:Label>
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>`

Code:

`(UpdateProgress1.FindControl("lbl_wait") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label).Text = "Logged In...";`